# Include libs folder containing .jars for compilation

Tags: java, ant, compilation, classpath, javac

I have the following file structure:

```
ServerCode <- src , libs, bin
```

I am trying to compile all the code in src. Src has a couple of .java files at the top level and sub-directories. libs contains all the .jar files which are required to build my project.

I wrote the following build.xml but when I try to compile it, the compiler throws errors cannot find symbol errors for the libraries I am including.

```
<project default="compile">
    <target name="compile">
        <mkdir dir="bin"/>
        <javac srcdir="src" destdir="bin" classpath="libs/*.jar">
    </target>
</project>
```

Comment: Try Giving absolute path  where all jars lie instead of libs/*.jar .Also is it libs or lib?

Comment: Yeah I was giving the relative path, thought it would work. I tried giving the full path but no luck...

Comment: could you tell me where lib folder exist and where build.xml exist?

Comment: ServerCode -> bin,libs,src, build.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define class path to include all jars like this

```
<target name="compile" depends=""   description="compile the java source files">  
   <javac srcdir="." destdir="${build}">  
        <classpath>  
            <fileset dir="${lib}">  
                <include name="**/*.jar" />  
            </fileset>  
            <fileset dir="${test_lib}">  
                <include name="**/*.jar" />  
            </fileset>  
        </classpath>  
    </javac>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use a pattern in the classpath attribute.  I could be wrong about this.  You should run ant in verbose mode (the -v option) to see how it's using your classpath attribute.  I suspect it's passing it to javac as a literal string.

Here's what I do:

```
<javac target="${javac.target}" source="${javac.source}" destdir="${validator.output.dir}" debug="on"
       nowarn="off"
       memorymaximumsize="128m" fork="true">
    <classpath refid="validator.module.production.classpath"/>
    <src>
        <dirset dir="Validator">
            <include name="src"/>
        </dirset>
    </src>
</javac>
```

...

```
<path id="validator.module.production.classpath">
    <fileset dir="Validator/lib/-validator" includes="**/*.jar"/>
</path>
```

Some of this code is generated by my IDE so it's a little verbose, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try this as mentioned at http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html instead of giving classPath attribute alongwith javac

```
  <classpath>
      <pathelement location="libs/*.jar"/>
    </classpath>
```

There are other ways also which you can glance thru the link mentioned above